# Will scrollHeight ever be smaller than clientHeight or offsetHeight?

Tags: javascript, dom

If I write `Math.max(el.scrollHeight, el.offsetHeight, el.clientHeight)` will this always equal `el.scrollHeight`?

Generally, `clientHeight <= offsetHeight <= scrollHeight`. There are rare cases where `clientHeight > offsetHeight` for the `html` element, but I'm not sure if `scrollHeight` can ever be smaller than the other two.

Answer (score 1):

The offsetHeight property includes the borders of elements so can definitely be greater than scrollHeight. E.g.

```js
let test = document.getElementById('test');
console.log("clientHeight = " + test.clientHeight);
console.log("offsetHeight = " + test.offsetHeight);
console.log("scrollHeight = " + test.scrollHeight);
console.log("Max Height = " 
    + Math.max(test.scrollHeight, test.offsetHeight, test.clientHeight));
```

```css
#test {
  height:20px;
  border:0px solid red;
  border-block-width: 20px;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```